# Adding to $PS1 variable on Git Bash for Windows using ~/.bash_profile causes an issue with __git_ps1

Tags: bash

So I am trying to customize the PS1 value to add a check mark or x to the prompt depending on the result of the previous command. Surprisingly I got that part to work fine.

However, it has broken the part of the prompt that shows the Git branch when viewing a Git repository.

Here is the previous PS1 value:

```
user@PC MINGW64 ~/Git
$ echo $PS1
\[\033]0;$TITLEPREFIX:$PWD\007\]\n\[\033[32m\]\u@\h \[\033[35m\]$MSYSTEM \[\033[33m\]\w\[\033[36m\]`__git_ps1`\[\033[0m\]\n$
```

and here is the new ~/.bash_profile script that breaks it:

```
function nonzero_return() {
    RETVAL=$?
    if [[ $RETVAL -ne 0 ]]
    then
        echo "❌ ($RETVAL)"
    else
        echo "✅"
    fi
}

export PS1="\[\e[31m\]\`nonzero_return\`\[\e[m\]\[\033]0;$TITLEPREFIX:$PWD\007\]\n\[\033[32m\]\u@\h \[\033[35m\]$MSYSTEM \[\033[33m\]\w\[\033[36m\]`__git_ps1`\[\033[0m\]\n$"
```

Here is an example of the old prompt versus the new one:

```
user@PC MINGW64 ~/Git/docker-brew-ubuntu-core (dist-amd64)
$


✅
user@PC MINGW64 ~/Git/docker-brew-ubuntu-core
$


❌ (127)
user@PC MINGW64 ~/Git/docker-brew-ubuntu-core
$
```

**SOLUTION**

Thanks to @davlet, @joanis, and @torek for helping me resolve this issue. I also used some other suggestions from them to edit my PS1 value even further into a place that I really liked. If anyone is curious, here is the new ~/.bash_profile script:

```
function nonzero_return() {
    local RETVAL=$?
    if [[ $RETVAL -ne 0 ]]
    then
        echo "❌($RETVAL)"
    else
        echo "✅"
    fi
}

PS1='\[\e]0;Git Bash: $MSYSTEM\007\]\n\[\e[31m\]`nonzero_return`\[\e[32m\] \u@\h \[\e[35m\]\w\[\e[36m\]`__git_ps1`\e[0m\n$'
```

Comment: Nothing to do with Git or Windows here, just your basic bash tricks. Side note: `\[...\]` in bash prompt strings is a trick needed for bash's use of `readline()`: bash needs to know at which column the cursor winds up after printing the prompt, and some sequences, such as color-change requests, take no columns even though they seem to take some. The `\[` sequence tells bash "stop counting" and `\]` tells it "resume counting". Because you have a newline embedded here after the status code, you don't need this at all!

Comment: @torek Ah, understood. These were actually added by Git Bash itself when it installed I guess. I have removed those at the end of the string and put the solution in my original question. Thanks!

Comment: On the other hand, they're harmless (except for reading comprehension anyway...). Peculiarly, they only work when they appear directly in the PS1 setting itself: putting them in a string that's interpolated with `$`, or in output from `$(...)` or backquotes, doesn't work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to steal that prompt, I really like it!

You just need to escape the backticks around `__git_ps1`:

```
export PS1="\[\e[31m\]\`nonzero_return\`\[\e[m\]\[\033]0;$TITLEPREFIX:$PWD\007\]\n\[\033[32m\]\u@\h \[\033[35m\]$MSYSTEM \[\033[33m\]\w\[\033[36m\]\`__git_ps1\`\[\033[0m\]\n$"
```

The difference is

```
...\`__git_ps1\`...
```

instead of

```
...`__git_ps1`...
```

in the export statement.

##### A bit of an explanation

The way the `PS1` variable works is that it gets evaluated each time the prompt is printed. That's why you can have functions in it like `__git_ps1` or your `nonzero_return` do something different each time the prompt is printed.

When you use double quotes to define `PS1`, e.g.:

```
PS1="...`my_function`...$MYVAR..."  # won't work
```

the shell applies normal double quote expansion right when `PS1` is defined, which includes expanding that backtick'd function call, and filling in the current value of `$MYVAR`, storing only the results in `PS1`, which is not what you want.

If you escape the backticks, or, better yet, use single quotes as @davlet said, `PS1` now contains those backticks and variables themselves, which get evaluation each time the prompt is printed.

You can give it a try: if you use single quotes and then change the value of `$MSYSTEM`, your prompt will reflect that change right away. The get the same effect with double quotes, you'd have to escape the `$`.

##### Getting rid of that newline

In the comments, you ask how to remove the newline after the checkmark or X.  That newline comes from the `\n` you have in the middle of your `PS1` definition. But I personally like that newline, because it means my prompt is preceded by a blank line, separating it more nicely from the output of the previous command, especially if that didn't output its own newline.

Here's how I would tweak your prompt:

```
PS1='\[\033]0;$TITLEPREFIX:$PWD\007\]\n\[\e[31m\]`nonzero_return`\[\e[m\]\[\033[32m\]\u@\h \[\033[35m\]$MSYSTEM \[\033[33m\]\w\[\033[36m\]`__git_ps1`\[\033[0m\]\n$'
```

Details:

- `\[\033]0;$TITLEPREFIX:$PWD\007\]` sets the Window's title bar
- `\n` separates the prompt from the previous command's output
- `[\e[31m\]`nonzero_return`\[\e[m\]` your return code function in bold red (note that the `\[\e[m|]` is superfluous here: it says reset the colour, but your next thing sets the colour again)
- `\[\033[32m\]\u@\h` user@host in green
- `\[\033[35m\]$MSYSTEM` the value of `$MSYSTEM` in purple
- `\[\033[33m\]\w` current working directory in yellow
- `` \[\033[36m\]`__git_ps1` ``  is the Git status in Cyan
- `\[\033[0m\]` resets the font
- `\n` is the newline
- `$` is the "superuser indicator" which turns to `#` when you are the superuser.

More notes:

- As @torek points out, `\[` and `\]` are unnecessary before the final `\n`
- You mix `\e` and `\033`: those are both escape sequences inserting an actual escape character in there. I prefer to use `\e` everywhere because I find it more legible.
- This is a useful reference on bash prompts: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Bash/Prompt_customization

Comment: Thanks! I think this would have probably worked as well but the answer by davlet did the job.

Comment: Actually did a quick test to confirm and this does work as well. It was important to escape the backticks around my function though, something I took out as part of @davlet's solution, or else it didn't work.

Comment: Escaping the backticks or not is the key, indeed! In a single-quoted string, there is no interpretation by the shell, you get exactly what's in the string. So no need to escape the backticks. But in a double-quoted string, those backticks get evaluated when PS1 is defined, which means they don't get re-evaluated each time the prompt is printed. That's why you need to escape them.

Comment: This makes perfect sense especially with the output I was getting. Essentially, without the backticks, I was just getting the check mark (the first evaluation) and never the X or error code. Like you said, it only got evaluated the one time.

Comment: I was looking through your comment and they are some amazing notes, thank you. I replaced all of the '\033' with '\e' and it worked perfectly. 

Also, you mentioned that you liked the new line because it separates nicely from the previous command. But, interestingly enough, there is a always a new line between my previous command and the new prompt on Git Bash (not on any other bash shell I use though like ubuntu). Where could this new line be coming from? I thought maybe PS0 but there was nothing in that when I echo'd it

Comment: The default PS1 variable in Git Bash has that newline, I believe.

Comment: Okay, yeah I'm dumb and didn't realize that the \n before my function was actually giving me the new line after my output from the previous command. Thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to use single quotes when assigning to PS1, and loose the backslashes before backticks. Also PS1 shouldn’t be exported:

```
PS1='\[\e[31m\]`nonzero_return`[...]'
```

Also, make RETVAL local in your helper function, otherwise it may interfere with other scripts, ie:

```
local RETVAL=$?
```

Comment: Good point, single quotes would work better than double quotes.

Comment: I have another question, the check mark is on a different line than the rest of the prompt. Is there a way I could I make it all into one line?

@joanis If you have an answer I'd love to hear it as well

Comment: `echo -n ...` won’t add a newline at the end

Comment: @Net-worker You actually have a `\n` around the middle of your `PS1` definition. That's why it's on a separate line.

Comment: @joanis I didn't even notice that \n before the '\u@\h' Thanks for the help! I actually kept the \n there and moved my function over. This was because I liked how the activated python virtual environment was on a new line but wanted to keep my function return on the same line. I will post the new values in the original question